# Array capacity limit in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I dont know how to set array capacity so my array can store only 3 elements. E.g. if I try to push 4th element, it returns error.
Any ideas?

Comment: That's not how Ruby arrays work. Better to use some wrapper class. Shameless plug, I wrote a gem that should cover your needs: https://github.com/citizen428/revolver

Answer (score 6):

The default `Array` class doesn't have that functionality. So, your options are:

1. Create a separate class that stores the three elements and implement your own methods like `push` and `[]`.
2. Subclass `Array` and override the methods to only allow for three elements, for example:

   ```
   class ThreeElements < Array
     def push(*stuff)
       raise 'Already has three elements!' unless length < 3
       super
     end
   end
   ```

In my opinion, #1 is the better option, because the default Array interface has too many methods to bother with overriding.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper class for your array! You can also override the "[]" operator in and check if your index is valid:

```
def [](i)
    # getter
end

def []=(i, v)
    # setter
end
```